# how to map @JsonProperty for an attribute having chance of multiple data types

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

Im using jsonProperty annonation to map json values to variables in pojo object.

```
{
  "valueSet": [
   {
     "name": "Type_int",
     "value": 123
   },
   {
     "name": "Type_String",
     "value": "ABC"
   }
  ]
}
```

For this above json, I am using Object class object to capture "value" attribute value.
like

```
@JsonProperty("value")
private Object value;
```

This working fine to capture both "Integer" and "String" value.

But for below scenario

```
{
   "valueSet": [
      {
        "name": "Type_int",
        "value": 123
      },
      {
        "name": "Type_String",
        "value": "ABC"
      },
      {
         "name": "Type_array",
         "value": [
            {
              "x": 0,
              "y": 0
            },
            {
              "x": 10,
              "y": 10
            },
            {
              "x": 20,
              "y": 20
            }
            ]
      }
      ]
}
```

There are three different data types for "value" attribute.I cannot use Object to capture value. So, is there any way to capture all values in "value" attribute.

Comment: Why can't you use `Object`?

Comment: You can, but you should cast it accordingly

Comment: Its not working for array of values @CassioMazzochiMolin

Comment: @NiveR, not able to cast, It is returning raw json as string.

Comment: This is a perfect situation for a Jackson custom deserializer. Simply extend [StdDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdDeserializer.html) and override the `deserialize(...)` method to support all three types you require.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying my luck, with below code,

The **Value** class

```
public class Value {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private Object value;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private ValueObject valueObject;

    //setters and getters
}
```

**ValueSet** class

```
public class ValueSet {

    @JsonProperty("valueSet")
    private List<Value> l;

    //setters & getters
}
```

**ValueObject** class

```
public class ValueObject {

    @JsonProperty("x")
    private int x;

    @JsonProperty("y")
    private int y;

    //setters & getters
}
```

And the test method

```
@Test
public void test() {
    String input = "{\"valueSet\":[{\"name\":\"Type_int\",\"value\":123},{\"name\":\"Type_String\",\"value\":\"ABC\"},{\"name\":\"Type_array\",\"value\":[{\"x\":0,\"y\":0},{\"x\":10,\"y\":10},{\"x\":20,\"y\":20}]}]}";
    //String input = "{\"valueSet\":[{\"name\":\"Type_int\",\"value\":123},{\"name\":\"Type_String\",\"value\":\"ABC\"}]}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        ValueSet v = mapper.readValue(input, ValueSet.class);
        System.out.println(v);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output, in reverse order.

```
ValueSet [l=[Value [name=Type_int, value=123], Value [name=Type_String, value=ABC]]]
ValueSet [l=[Value [name=Type_int, value=123], Value [name=Type_String, value=ABC], Value [name=Type_array, value=[{x=0, y=0}, {x=10, y=10}, {x=20, y=20}]]]]
```

Add `toString()` methods to see output in `log` or console. And somehow this works for me. Not sure if it would work for you.

Comment: I tried this, get this issue Conflicting setter definitions for property "value"

Comment: I had Jackson 2.8.x as JSON library.

Comment: I am using jackson 2.9.x library.

Comment: I executed the same code with Jackson 2.9.5 library this time, and it is still working fine. I had Jackson 2.8.11.1 earlier. The error that you mentioned occurs when you place `json-annotations` on setters rather than fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("valueSet");
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(jsonArray.optJSONObject(i).get("value").toString());
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain *why* this is an answer. How does this solve the problem of the OP?